# Phantomjs - writing data with fs.write() to a new line is not going to the next line

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I cannot get phantomjs to write to a new line. I can get it to replace the data, I can get it to write to the end, I can get it to register the "\n" code but it just removes it from the string and does not implement it.

The following is an example of some code im using to write to file.

```
fs.write("example.txt", "write me first", "a");
fs.write("example.txt", "\n write me to the next line bro!", "a");
```

but it outputs as follows

```
 write me first write me to the next line bro!
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Its hard to view an error log with history on it if its all on one line.

I have tried "\n" and "\r"

-----edit------

Ive since become a somewhat stronger developer. I now realize this was right the whole time. This was not an issue with my code, or even phantomjs/casperjs, but rather a problem with notepad.

I was not using an ide, due to my want of simplicity. Because of this, I ran into issues where microsoft would try to reformat things in notepad.

If any other newbies are using notepad, or any other default text editor, you may experience this as well.

Consider switching to one of many ides or code editors. Simplistic ones notepad++ on windows or textwrangler on mac should give you a somewhat similar feel to the default editors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my old post. I reworded it to sound more professional.

The mentioned issue was a problem with microsoft notepad. It ignores certain carriages. Im sure there is a way to make it register them, but it was not on by default on the windows 7 comp I was on at the time.

A more advanced editor, or basically any code editor/ide should be able to pick up the carriages.

**For the other newbies, carriages are basically raw code for "next line."**

^^>>I am aware this is not likely the technical response to this, but is a decent and clear response for a newbie, who will likely be one of the ones finding this page through google. Please do not edit this to a super advanced definition.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Answer (score 3):

Windows uses \r\n for newlines.

\r is a carriage return, \n is a newline.

This is a reference to the old typewriters which needed to bring the typing head (carriage) back to the beginning of each new line.

Comment: I marked you answer up but did not select it. The issue I had was an issue that mainly only newbies would have. I didnt understand the problem I was having. You still gave a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

What version of PhantomJS are you using?

Under Linux, with PhantomJS 1.9.7, I can use the following `test.js`:

```
fs = require('fs');
fs.write("test.dat", "write me first", "a");
fs.write("test.dat", "\nwrite me to the next line", "a");
phantom.exit();
```

to get the following output in `test.dat` from running `phantomjs test.js`:

```
write me first
write me to the next line
```

Comment: 1.9.2 let me upgrade real quick and see if that fixes it. I really hope thats the fix.

Comment: Sorry for the problems. I figured it out. Notepad shouldnt be allowed to exist. Im deleting the question.
-edit- wont let me delete. I left an answer in case someone else has the same issue

Comment: *"Notepad shouldnt be allowed to exist."* - tell that to Microsoft :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you open output file with notepad++, you will get the data with new line. Normal notepad doesn't show break lines.